# How to use systemd aliases with journalctl?

Tags: systemd, journalctl

I defined a systemd service, which has a name I always mistype (kafka in this instance) so I gave it a few easy aliases. In the systemd files, it means that I have the line:

```
Alias=k.service kakfa.service
```

Which make my inner sloth very happy as I can now use `service k start` or not bother about the `kakfa` typo.

When I want to check the logs, though, I still need to type the full original name, `journaltcl -u k` will not work, as in it will only output the laconic `-- No entries --`.

No googling or reading man pages helped. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you be able to add an extra alias entry for the journaltcl command?ex: `alias jfk="journalctl -fk"` in a more similar fashion as required either for your kafka or systemd service.

Comment: It is of course possible but it's really not what I am looking for. If systemd aliases are defined somewhere, I want to use them without having to duplicate definitions or create personal commands.

Answer (score -1):

In your 'Alias' example you miss-typed "kafka" unless this was for illustrative purpose I would start by changeing "kakfa" to "kafka", i.e. the source code should look like this:

Alias=k.service kafka.service

Comment: I believe you've missed the main point of the question.